# Compatability issues with Mac OS X 10.6 application

Tags: xcode, macos

I tried to test the USBPrivateDataSample application downloaded from developer.apple.com. I tried to run the application but it is showing error like, "error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk".

I am using mac osx 10.6. And target the application to 10.6. But still I am getting the same error, I don't know where I need to change the target OSX, I have already changed the targets of MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6. Still I am getting the same error,

Can you guys please help me on this?

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Comment: You need to either install the 10.4 SDK or change the SDK in your Xcode project settings.

Comment: I changed that Paul, and now I am getting the following error "Invalid value '4.0' for GCC_VERSION_i386" Can you please help me?

Comment: Sure - just change GCC_VERSION to 4.2 in the Xcode project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Base SDK to the 10.6 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xcode 3.x with mac os x 10.6 then double click on target in project navigator. There will be open build setting change base sdk to 10.5